# What is the correct way to set a custom primaryKey attribute in the latest build of ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've seen a few ways to do this but I'm curious what the "most correct" approach is using the latest build (master even) of ember-data rev 12

Option #1 (would appear the most obvious way)

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id',
    _id: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Option #2 (map it using the adapter by type)

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Post', {
    primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Option #3 (hard code it in the serializer -assumes every model has the same custom pk)

```
App.MySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: function(type) {
        return '_id';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is option #2 as Adapter is the concerning component. Adapter needs to know which property is the primary key. It is not important for model or serializer.

Comment: do you know of a good example that shows this in the wild? discourse or some other OSS project maybe?

Comment: Discourse does not use Ember Data. But look here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#mapping

Comment: is this still valid, according to documentation the serializer is supposed to know about the id-key: http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey

Answer (score 1):

This question is very old, but it hasn't an accepted answer and it showed up on google for me.

The current answer is to set this up on the serializer ( https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_ids )

```
// app/serializers/application.js

import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in this thread, try https://github.com/toranb/ember-data-django-rest-adapter/issues/14

```
YourRestadapter.configure('App.Person', {
    primaryKey: 'slug'
});
```

**YourRestadapter = the rest adapter you use in your project (e.g., DS.RESTAdapter)**